# How to save an IplImage?

Tags: c, opencv

When we have an [IplImage](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#iplimage), how can we save it so we can use it later, or view it as an image outside of our code (such as via png, or jpeg)?

As a code example, I have the following:

```
void SaveImage()
{
    CvSize size;
    IplImage *rgb_img;
    int i = 0;

    size.height = HEIGHT;
    size.width = WIDTH;

    rgb_img = cvCreateImageHeader(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    rgb_img->imageData = my_device.ColorBuffer;
    rgb_img->imageDataOrigin = rgb_img->imageData;

    /*for (i = 2; i < rgb_img->imageSize; i+= 3)
    {
        // confirming all values print correctly
        printf("%d, ", rgb_img->imageData[i]);
    }*/

    cvSaveImage("foo.png",rgb_img);
}
```

I have printed out all of the values in the commented out for loop, and it seems like the data is in the buffer correctly.  Using cvShowImage to display the image also works correctly, so it seems like the structure of the image is fine.

Comment: If you have a 3-channel image (IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3), how does printing only the first channel as in your for loop showing you all the values in your buffer?

Comment: This is a good point.  I was just testing out to make sure that the rgb_img->imageData assignment didn't fail.

Comment: However, now that you've mentioned it, there are several negative values in the imageData.  That doesn't seem possible.  None of the values in ColorBuffer are negative (I just checked)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void SaveImage()
{
    CvSize size;
    IplImage *rgb_img;
    int i = 0;

    size.height = HEIGHT;
    size.width = WIDTH;

    rgb_img = cvCreateImageHeader(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    rgb_img->imageData = my_device.ColorBuffer;

    // You should NOT have the line below or OpenCV will try to deallocate your data
    //rgb_img->imageDataOrigin = rgb_img->imageData;

    for (i = 0; i < size.height; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0;j < size.width; j++)
        {
        // confirming all values print correctly
        printf("%c, ", rgb_img->imageData[i*width + j]);
        }
    }

    cvSaveImage("foo.png",rgb_img);
}
```

Running this should not crash.

Some problems with your code

- You use %f to print but IPL_DEPTH_8U is 1-byte uchar

Comment: Does this work with IplImage* instead of a CvArr*?  I tried this, setting setting the filename to "foo.png" and it gave a memory violation.

Comment: Of course it does. CvArr* means IplImage* or CvMat*. Since you get memory violation error, you should put more code in your post. You must have made some error in handling the image.

Comment: It does. And I get notifications when you update stuff so you don't have to reply to comments to indicate so. Welcome to StackOverflow as well.

Comment: Thanks so much.  The culpirt was the assignment of imageDataOrigin.  I appreciate it

Comment: is there a way to save the image to a specifik path ?

Comment: Instead of "foo.png", give it whatever path you want.

Comment: I get `error: ‘cvSaveImage’ was not declared in this scope` compilation error while using cvSaveImage as shown above. Seems like a linking error. Is there any way we can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To save:

```
cvSaveImage(outFileName,img)
```

If you wanted to check it had saved, you could do the following:

```
  if(!cvSaveImage(outFileName,img)) printf("Could not save: %s\n",outFileName);
```

Taken from http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00052000000000000000 - top result on Google for "opencv write iplimage".

Comment: This does not appear to be working.  I did check this website beforehand.  It is giving me a memory access violation.  "Access violation reading location 0x00000280."